# Excel Dates and R?

Tags: r, excel, date, plot

I have a short data frame I randomly created to have a practice before it gets to Big Data frames. I made it with the same Variables as the original should be but way shorter.

[image: Date plot]

The problem I'm having is that Excel takes dates with month first, so R is confused and it's putting 10/1/2015 first. When it's supposed to be last.

- What can I do so R correctly orders the dates?

Also I want to for example calculate the Total amount of money (Data$Total) that I made in one month.

- What would be the script for that?

Also if I'm already here I could kill two birds with one stone. I know there is already an answer for this, but the answer I saw involves using Direct.labels package that completely messes up with the whole graphic.

- What would you advise to prevent the labels going over the plot
  margin?

[image: missing Labels]

DPUT()

```
 dput(Data)
structure(list(JOB = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("JAGER", 
"PLAY", "RUGBY"), class = "factor"), AGENCY = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("LONDON", "WILHEL"), class = "factor"), 
    DATE = structure(c(4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("10/1/2015", 
    "10/3/2015", "10/9/2015", "9/24/2015", "9/26/2015"), class = "factor"), 
    RATE = c(90L, 90L, 100L, 90L, 90L), HS = c(8L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 
    4L), TOTAL = c(720L, 540L, 400L, 540L, 360L)), .Names = c("JOB", 
"AGENCY", "DATE", "RATE", "HS", "TOTAL"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: First off your images are the same, second could you `dput()` your data so we can see what you're working with, third trying using 'as.Date(x, format="%d/%m/%Y")' to define your style of date. [This](http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html) will give you the info on how to set up your dates, you can arrange them in any way. Lastly when you plot you can use xaxt='n' inside `plot()` and `axis()` to set up your own axis. Hope that helps!

Comment: @HoneyDippedBadger Im so sorry!! I edited the post now! And yes already you helped me massively with that! Thanks a lot, really appreaciatte it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I went about what you're after:

rugger is the dataset I constructed from your `dput()`

```
plot(order(as.Date(rugger$DATE,"%m/%d/%Y")),rugger$TOTAL,xaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="Total")
labs <- as.Date(rugger$DATE,"%m/%d/%Y")
axis(side = 1,at = rugger$DATE,labels = rep("",5))
text(cex=1, x=order(as.Date(rugger$DATE,"%m/%d/%Y"))+0.1, y=min(rugger$TOTAL)-25, labs, xpd=TRUE, srt=45, pos=2)
```

The text call allows you to manipulate the labels far more, srt is a rotation call. I used `order()` to put the days in chronological order, this will also turn them into the numbers that represent those Dates as ordered Dates appeared to be managed as factors (I'm not positive on that, it's just what I'm seeing).

If you don't want dots check out the `pch` argument within `plot()`. [Pch types.](http://coleoguy.blogspot.ca/2012/10/pch.html)

Comment: You are a Star! Thank you very much. What you taught me is really good. Now how would you separate the TOTAL in months, for example if i want to know how much i earned each month.

Comment: Not a problem, glad to be of help!

Comment: Really really helpful!

Comment: Hi Honey! lol. Your script worked perfect till i added more dates to the CSV. Its giving me this error 
Error in axis(side = 1, at = Data$Date, labels = rep("", 7)) : 
  no locations are finite
In addition: Warning message:
In axis(side = 1, at = Data$Date, labels = rep("", 7)) :
  NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: Sounds like the dates you added did not conform to the data standard you had established earlier in the dataset. Can you add in the data where this issue was seen?

Comment: I already solved it!  Just a matter of restarting R! Thanks for your concern

Comment: Self taught, necessity breeds creativity. This community is very strong, has taught me a lot. Just read everything you can and you'll find stuff you never knew R could do. Dates are in my mind the most complicated part of data management. But packages like lubridate help alot. Though much of what packages can do, base R can do with a little extra work.

Comment: Agree. Just sitting 30 min each day and getting better day after day. Thank you tho 4 your advices!